# Android: Unable to put multiple values into Intent/Bundle

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I've been trying to use an Intent to pass multiple values (of different types) between two Activities. So far I've tried these two approaches:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Receiver.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("key1", v1);
bundle.putString("key2", v2);
bundle.putString("key3", v3);
bundle.putInt("key4", v4);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

and:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Receiver.class);
intent.putInt("key1", v1);
intent.putString("key2", v2);
intent.putString("key3", v3);
intent.putInt("key4", v4);
```

However, it seems only the value for `key1` is retained in both cases (when using a Bundle, it apparently only contains 1 key). What am I missing?

**Edit:** This is how I retrieve the values in `Receiver`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    v1 = bundle.getInt("key1", DEFAULT1);
    v2 = bundle.getString("key2", "DEFAULT2");
    v3 = bundle.getString("key3", "DEFAULT3");
    v4 = bundle.getInt("key4", DEFAULT4);

    // ...
}
```

Alternatively:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    v1 = intent.getIntExtra("key1", DEFAULT1);
    v2 = intent.getStringExtra("key2");
    v3 = intent.getStringExtra("key3");
    v4 = intent.getIntExtra("key4", DEFAULT2);

    // ...
}
```

When I print out the values of `v1`, `v2`, `v3`, and `v4`, `v1` is the only one with a non-null/non-default value (the value I initially put in `key1` - actually, all of the values I originally put into the Intent were non-default).

**Edit 2:**

I tried using `getBundleExtra()` like so:

```
intent.putExtra("bundle", bundle);
```

And then in `Receiver`:

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("bundle");
```

However, `bundle` was null.

**Edit 3:**

Changing the order in which values are put in/retrieved from the Intent doesn't appear to affect anything. Nor does specifying the capacity of the Bundle. If it helps, this Intent is used in a PendingIntent.

Comment: "However, it seems only the value for key1 is retained in both cases" -- how are you determining this?

Comment: How are you retrieving values?

Comment: Edited my question with the code - I simply use `getExtras()` for a Bundle and `getExtra` if no Bundle. Additionally, I printed out all the retrieved values and compared them against the defaults.

Comment: This is unlikely. I do this on regular basis without any problem. The problem could be some where else. Post your entire code of the both activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I overlooked something really simple - my Intent was used in a PendingIntent to fire a receiver and then start a service, but I forgot to properly transfer the Bundle from the original Intent to the (new, different) Intent that was ultimately received by the second Activity (which was started by the service). The problem's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass and receive Intent Extras without using Bundle.

**SenderClass.java**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Receiver.class);
intent.putExtra("key1", key1);
intent.putExtra("key2", key2);
intent.putExtra("key3", key3);
startActivity(intent)
```

**Receiver.java**

```
String key1 = getIntent().getStringExtra("key1");
String key2 = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
String key3 = getIntent().getStringExtra("key3");
```

Comment: I tried this already (the code is in my question). Neither way worked.